# Why can't I scale/rotate/translate properly and what is that orange line?

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image: the orang line is the problem]

Whenever I try to move/scale or rotate and object (I'm zoomed in) the orange line appears and the object gets reeeaally big and is deformed :/ Whenever I'm zoomed out that line doesn't appear any more.
It didn't happen before, what should I do to fix this?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with snapping. The orange circle at the left end of the orange line (between the two black arrows) is what I would expect to see when you have snapping turned on. You have the 3Dview tool-bar doodad hidden, so I can't see what snap mode you have enabled. I might have put this in as an actual answer but I don't know what the orange line is nor why it appears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That comment alone helped me :D so what so I have to do to make that snap go away? Sorry I'm new to Blender

Comment: Oh its alright, I've got this XD

Comment: I'll make this the answer, then...

Answer (score 1):

Snapping mode is turned on, and your scaling operation is snapping to nearby geometry, giving you unexpected results.
Simply turn off snapping mode (hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and your issue should be resolved.